# Printing widgets Id in kivy

Tags: python, dictionary, kivy, widget, ids

Is there a way to check or print a widgets id if you are not sure what id it has? I have a layout I made, its a simple BoxLayout where my Label has its id(its done in the kv file), than I use that Layout multiple times in a GridLayout. Now I have multiple Labels, but they technically have the same id or maybe kivy changes the id if you use it multiple times? Thats what I wanted to check by printining all their ids.

a3.py

```py
from BareBones import Skeleton

menu = ['espresso', 'latte', 'capuccino', 'nescafe', 'Sahlep', 'Mahlep']
keys = []


class Double(BoxLayout):
    pass
class NewLayout(GridLayout):
    def set_text(self,text):
        print(self.root.ids.Skeleton.ids['label_id'].text)


    pass

class MainPage(BoxLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)


        iterator = 1



        for i in range(len(menu)):
            b = Button(size=(100,50))
            self.ids[str(iterator)] = b

            self.add_widget(b)

            keys.append(str(iterator))
            iterator = iterator+1
            print(keys)
            print(len(menu))

        for x, y in zip(menu, keys):
            self.ids[y].text = x


class RightSide(BoxLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.orientation='vertical'

        for i in range(len(menu)):
            self.add_widget(Skeleton())






kv = Builder.load_file("b3.kv")


class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return kv

MainApp().run()
```

b3.kv

```py
NewLayout:

    cols: 2
    MainPage:
    RightSide:



<MainPage>:
    orientation: 'vertical'



<Skeleton>
    b1: b1
    b2: b2
    label_id: label_id

    Button:
        id: b1
        text:'+'
        on_press: root.on_button_click_plus()

    Label:
        id: label_id


    Button:
        id: b2
        text:'-'
        on_press: root.on_button_click_minus()
```

BareBones.py

```py
class Skeleton(BoxLayout):
    count = 0
    my_text = ''
    drink_name = ''

    def on_button_click_plus(self):
        print("Button clicked")
        self.count += 1
        self.ids.label_id.text = str(self.count)
        self.my_text = str(self.count)
        return self.my_text
    def on_button_click_minus(self):
        print("Button clicked")
        self.my_text = str(self.count)
        self.ids.label_id.text = str(self.count)

        if self.count > 0:
            self.count -= 1
            self.ids.label_id.text = str(self.count)
        else:
            pass

    def trying(self):
        pass


class PlusMinus(BoxLayout):
    menu = ['espresso']
    keys = []

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.orientation='vertical'
        menu = self.menu

        self.add_widget(Skeleton())
```

So this basically looks like this:
[image: GUI]

What I basically want to do is have a button that collects all the labels texts (the numbers) So that I can pair them with the menu array to know how many of them were added to our basket. I also want to reset the labels however I dont know how I can get the texts that are so far deep in the code.

Answer (score 1):

If you change the `drink_name` to a `StringProperty` in the `Skeleton` class:

```
class Skeleton(BoxLayout):
    count = 0
    my_text = ''
    drink_name = StringProperty('')
```

and assign a value to that property when each `Skeleton` instance is created:

```
class RightSide(BoxLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.orientation='vertical'

        for i in range(len(menu)):
            self.add_widget(Skeleton(drink_name=menu[i]))
```

Then you can get a tally of the number of drinks added with a method in the `MainPage` class:

```
def tally(self):
    rightside = kv.ids.rightside
    for skel in rightside.children:
        if isinstance(skel, Skeleton):
            print(skel.drink_name, skel.ids.label_id.text)
```

Plus one other required change. In your `kv`, add an `id` for the `RightSide` instance:

```
NewLayout:

    cols: 2
    MainPage:
    RightSide:
        id: rightside
```

Comment: So the app runs like that but nothing different happens, how do I use this tally function. Also there is a warning when we use kv in the MainPage(it doesnt give an error when it runs tho but I dont think I used the function yet) I think the error is " UnboundLocalError: local variable 'kv' referenced before assignment"

Comment: I also bound the tally method to a button and it gave an error as well

Comment: So after many tries the most common error I get is this one:      rightside = kv.ids.rightside
   File "kivy/properties.pyx", line 864, in kivy.properties.ObservableDict.__getattr__
 AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: Oops! Forgot one required change. See my updated answer.

Comment: Oh wow that is actually amazing, can you explain how it exactly works. What does the "children" keyword exactly refer to? Is it a keyword to reference the buttons and labels under a widget?

Comment: See the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.widget.html#kivy.uix.widget.Widget.children).

Answer (score 0):

[image: error]
So this is the error Pycharm shows, the red highlighting under kv.

```py
class MainPage(BoxLayout):                                                                                    
                                                                                                              
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):                                                                             
        super().__init__(**kwargs)                                                                            
                                                                                                              
                                                                                                              
        iterator = 1                                                                                          
                                                                                                              
                                                                                                              
                                                                                                              
        for i in range(len(menu)):                                                                            
            b = Button(size=(100,50))                                                                         
            self.ids[str(iterator)] = b                                                                       
                                                                                                              
            self.add_widget(b)                                                                                
                                                                                                              
            keys.append(str(iterator))                                                                        
            iterator = iterator+1                                                                             
            print(keys)                                                                                       
            print(len(menu))                                                                                  
                                                                                                              
        for x, y in zip(menu, keys):                                                                          
            self.ids[y].text = x                                                                              
                                                                                                              
    def tally(self):                                                                                          
        rightside = self.kv.ids.rightside                                                                     
        for skel in rightside.children:                                                                       
            if isinstance(skel, Skeleton):                                                                    
                kv = Builder.load_file("b3.kv")                                                               
                print(skel.drink_name, skel.ids.label_id.text)                                                
                                                                                                              
                                                                                                              
                                                                                                              
class RightSide(BoxLayout):                                                                                   
                                                                                                              
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):                                                                             
        super().__init__(**kwargs)                                                                            
        self.orientation='vertical'                                                                           
                                                                                                              
        for i in range(len(menu)):                                                                            
            self.add_widget(Skeleton(drink_name=menu[i]))                                                     
                                                                                                              
                                                                                                              
                                                                                                              
                                                                                                              
                                                                                                              
                                                                                                              
                                                                                                              
kv = Builder.load_file("b3.kv")                                                                               
                                                                                                              
                                                                                                              
                                                                                                              
                                                                                                              
                                                                                                              
class MainApp(App):                                                                                           
    def build(self):                                                                                          
        return kv                                                                                             
                                                                                                              
                                                                                                              
                                                                                                              
                                                                                                              
                                                                                                              
MainApp().run()
```

So I changed the Stringproperty in the Skeleton file and the code looks like that with the changes you told me to add. However nothing happens, how do I actually use the tally() method?